# No attribute '__getitem__' in 'set' object in Twitter app

Tags: python, twitter

I am building a simple app that just streams the twitter stream for a user, and keep getting error

```
File "scratch.py", line 6, in <module>
config['oauth_token'],
TypeError: 'set' object has no attribute '__getitem__'</code>
```

in line 6.

The source code is:

```
from twitter import TwitterStream

config = { --- add your 4 horsemen in this dictionary --- }
ts = TwitterStream(
                    auth=OAuth(
                        config['oauth_token'],
                        config['oauth_token_secret'],
                        config['key'],
                        config['secret']
                        )
                    )
openstream = ts.statuses.filter(track=words)
for item in openstream:
    print item['user']['screen_name'], datetime.strptime(item['created_at'],'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y'), item['text']
    if datetime.now() &gt; stop:
        print datetime.now().isoformat()
        break
```

The values for 'oauth-token' and other variables are of course application-specific, and I cannot reveal them here. I am a python newbie and cannot really understand the error here, and would be glad of any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your config dictionary has a typo somewhere in it that causes it to be created as a set, rather than a dictionary. Perhaps you typed `,` instead of `:` somewhere.

Comment: You are right, the question seems rather stupid ow, once you've answered it :P